# How can i query a large result set in Kusto explorer?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I am trying to return more than 1 million records from Kusto database in Kusto explorer but I am getting this error below

```
Query result set has exceeded the internal record count limit 500000 (E_QUERY_RESULT_SET_TOO_LARGE; see http://aka.ms/kustoquerylimits)
```

I think the limit is 5000000. Any ideas how can I achieve this? thanks

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/concepts/querylimits#limit-on-result-set-size-result-truncation

Answer (score 3):

```
set notruncation;
```

> It's strongly recommended that, in this case, some form of limitation
>   is still put in place.

```
set truncationmaxsize=YOUR_LIMIT;
set truncationmaxrecords=YOUR_LIMIT;
```

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/concepts/querylimits#limit-on-result-set-size-result-truncation

Comment: I configured the truncation property but I am getting this error 
"Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."

Answer (score 2):

For large data exports - please use server-export options described here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-export/

Service-side export (push): The methods above are somewhat limited since the query results have to be streamed through a single network connection between the producer doing the query and the consumer writing its results. For scalable data export, Kusto provides a "push" export model in which the service running the query also writes its results in an optimized manner. This model is exposed through a set of .export control commands, supporting exporting query results to an external table, a SQL table, or an external Blob storage.

Comment: Thank you, I have used the .export command and it was running pretty great but after one hour it returns the following error. 

The Summarize operator has exceeded the memory budget during evaluation. Results may be incorrect or incomplete (E_RUNAWAY_QUERY).

I have 32 gb physical memory on my VM

Comment: Check article describing how to overcome this error:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/shufflequery

Answer (score 0):

Additional option is to use Kusto Explorer "run query into csv" button, this will add the `set notruncation;` for you and will save the results directly to disk, so that you can easily open the results in other tools such as Excel.

[image]

Comment: I am getting this error "Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."

Comment: I can able to retrieve 1 million rows using the suggested way but my requirement is to retrieve 26 million records which raises the above error.

Comment: in that case you should use the .export command to Azure storage and process the file/s from there.

Comment: I have used .export command and it looks like it improves.. but after one hour of running the query(perfectly writing records into csv) it fails. the error is related to memory

The Summarize operator has exceeded the memory budget during evaluation. Results may be incorrect or incomplete (E_RUNAWAY_QUERY).

My physical memory is 32 gb.